# deploy jenkins on azure kubernetes

Tags: azure, jenkins, kubernetes, deployment, load-balancing

[ingress and service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZJlZ.png)

***PLEASE CLICK THE LINK TO VIEW THE IMAGE***

As a beginner, I tried to deploy Jenkins on azure Kubernetes. but I could not able to access the dashboard from the outside location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you do something wrong. Here is an example YAML file to deploy the Jenkins in AKS with a service and it's accessible:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins
        ports:
        - containerPort: 50000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: jenkins
  ports:
  - name: test1
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
```

screenshot of the access:

[image]

[image]

When the service is accessible, it's also accessible even if you add an ingress.

Comment: Thanks, dor your support. However, i have resolved my problem using bitnami helm https://bitnami.com/stack/jenkins/helm

Comment: @IOTTest That's nothing different. The chart just configures more things for you.

Comment: Thanks... Much appreciate